# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority while accessing web service (.asmx)

Tags: web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am getting "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority" error while accessing web service (.asmx).

This error is not coming for every request. We receive this error every 4 out of 10 requests and its random.

Need help here as We are stuck with this from couple of days.

Comment: Which technology(Java or Dotnet) you are using while implementing client

Comment: Hi @GaneshS , I'm having a similar issue as the one you mention. Was there any solution that you found for this problem? If yes, what was it?